# $(f(x,y))$ for irreducible $f$ is not closed in the Zariski topology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $f(x,y) \in \Bbb{C}[x,y]$ be an irreducible polynomial , therefore it defines a prime ideal $(f(x,y))$, I want to prove that it is not closed in the Zariski topology.

---

I want to use Hilbert Nullstansatz, the Zariski closed set one to one correspond to the radical ideal, but here $(f(x,y))$ is prime hence radical, therefore it's closed? Where goes wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "I want to prove that it is not closed in the Zariski topology"? There are multiple things you could mean and depending on what that is you could reach different conclusions (as evidenced by your later statements), so it's important to be precise here.

Comment: I heard this statement in an online course about algebraic geometry, if we denote $\frak{p}$ a prime ideal, denote $[p]\in \text{Spec}(A)$ (as a point in Spec) then here really means the point $[(f(x,y))]\in \text{Spec}(A)$ is not a closed point? is there other possibility @KReiser

Comment: Your use of the nullstellensatz later on suggests you were instead thinking about $V((f))$. As shown in the linked duplicate, a point in an affine scheme is closed iff it is a maximal ideal, so since $(f)$ is not maximal you're done.

Comment: Great , thank you KReiser

Comment: For completeness I made a comment, $(f)$ is not maximal since by the weak Hilbert Nullstansatz (which needs $\Bbb{C}$ to be algebraic closed), all the maximal ideal has the form $(x-a,y-b)$ since $(f)$ is principal this can not happens.

Comment: @yili Another way is touse [Krull's Hauptidealsatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krull%27s_principal_ideal_theorem) (which does not need an algebraically closed field): Any principal ideal (Hauptideal) has height at most one, so in a polynomial ring it can reduce the dimension by at most one. So any quotient of the form $k[x,y] / (f)$ has Krull dimension $\geq 1$, hence it cannot be a field.

Comment: Thank you red_trumpet , I learned Krull's Hauptidealsatz recently.